# In SQLAlchemy, is there a way to map a parent property onto a child for quick access?

Tags: orm, sqlalchemy

If I have

```
Category()
  products = db.relationship('Product', backref='category')
  name = Column(String())

Product()
  name = Column(String())
  category_id = Column(Integer(), ForiegnKey('category.id')
```

When I do

```
Product.query.join(Category).options(contains_eager(Product.category)).all()
```

I'd like to end up with a list of Products that have a 'pseudo' (or transient in ORM parlance) category_name field populated, so I don't have to interrogate the category like this

```
product.category.name
```

and can do this instead

```
product.category_name
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with [association proxies](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html):

```
class Product(Base):
    ...
    category_name = association_proxy("category", "name")
```